# How to include metadata on a requests API query

Tags: api, python-requests, metadata

I need to specify the page and offset to retrieve all the data from a CRM. On the API documentation it's specified:"All pagination related query parameters begin with page. List endpoints typically limit the number of entities returned. This is considered a “page” of results. There is a meta root property in the response, containing pagination metadata;

```
{
    "deals": [...],
    "meta": {
        "page": {
            "pageOffset": 0,
            "pageSize": 20,
            "count": 11394
        }   
    }
}
```

". But I don't know where to palce this infomation. I tried this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    
    }

params = {
    'pageSize':'40',
    'pageOffset':'2'
}
deals = requests.get('https://baud.teamwork.com/crm/api/v2/deals.json', headers=headers, params=params).json()
```

But he metadata "pageSize" and "pageOffset" are not properly specified

Comment: Can we see the documentation link?

Comment: https://developer.teamwork.com/crm/general/pagination

Comment: specifying `pageOffset` & `pageSize` as param seems to be documented. whats the error again?

Comment: Sorry Tarique, I was doing it properly but not visualizing it. My fault. Appreciate your help :)